# Updating EnvironmentObject from within the View Model

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I want to pass an environment object to a view model so I can change/update it. The EnvironmentObject is a simple AppState which consists of a single property counter.

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int = 0 
}
```

The view model "CounterViewModel" updates the environment object as shown below:

```
class CounterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var appState: AppState
    
    init(appState: AppState) {
        self.appState = appState
    }
    
    var counter: Int {
        appState.counter 
    }
    
    func increment() {
        appState.counter += 1
    }
    
}
```

The ContentView displays the value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var counterVM: CounterViewModel
    
    init(counterVM: CounterViewModel) {
        self.counterVM = counterVM
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(counterVM.counter)")
            Button("Increment") {
                counterVM.increment()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am also injecting the state as shown below:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            let appState = AppState()
            
            ContentView(counterVM: CounterViewModel(appState: appState))
                .environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click the increment button, the counterVM.counter never returns the updated value. What am I missing?

Comment: All ObservableObjects have to be wrapped with one of the Object wrappers you can’t put one inside the other and have them trigger changes. Sink is an option but not ideal.

Comment: Do you have a proposed solution?

Comment: The only solutions are mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: I am unable to understand the comment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `CounterViewModel` is an ObservableObject, but it has no `@Published` properties – so no changes will be published automatically to the views.

But you can manually publish changes by using `objectWillChange.send()`:

```
    func increment() {
        objectWillChange.send()
        appState.counter += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why both the CounterViewModel and the AppState need to be observable objects, since you are using a view model to format the content of your models. I would consider AppState to be a model and I could therefore define it as a struct. The CounterViewModel will then be the ObservableObject and it published the AppState. In this way your code is clean and works.

Code for AppState:

```
import Foundation

struct AppState {
    var counter: Int = 0
}
```

Code for CounterViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class CounterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var appState: AppState
    
    init(appState: AppState) {
        self.appState = appState
    }
    
    var counter: Int {
        appState.counter
    }
    
    func increment() {
        appState.counter += 1
    }
}
```

Code for the ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var counterVM = CounterViewModel(appState: AppState())
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(counterVM.counter)")
            Button("Increment") {
                counterVM.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do remind, that in the View where you first define an ObservableObject, you define it with @StateObject. In all the views that will also use that object, you use @ObservedObject.

This code will work.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have AppState as a struct. If that is the model that is held in the environment then it would be shared amongst many view models/views. You certainly want it as a reference type.

Comment: Yes. I want AppState to be a reference type.

Comment: @Paul, It wasn't clear in the post that AppState was to be shared among several view models or views. If so, you're absolutely right. You do want to have a class instead of a struct. Still, I would not use a model as an observable object if there is a view model in between.

Comment: Yes, your answer is 100% right on that. I guess the name "AppState" implies that this is a model for the whole app in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your `xxxxApp.swift` (used to be the `AppDelegate`) file ?
Sometimes Xcode would do it for you automatically, sometimes won't you have to add it manually and add your environment object. * It has to be the view that contains all the view you want to share the object to.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        VStack {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(YourViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We actually don't use view model objects in SwiftUI for view data. We use an `@State` struct and if we need to mutate it in a subview we pass in a binding, e.g.

```
struct Counter {
    var counter: Int = 0
    
    mutating func increment() {
       counter += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counter = Counter()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView2(counter: $counter)
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Binding var counter: Counter // if we don't need to mutate it then just use let and body will still be called when the value changes.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(counter.counter, format: .number) // the formatting must be done in body so that SwiftUI will update the label automatically if the region settings change.
            Button("Increment") {
                counter.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}
```